# Conditionally reading a cell with openpyxl, and updating tkinter label based on result

Tags: excel, python-3.x, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm trying to iterate through a column in excel and display the contents of that cell (finish when get to a blank cell) on a label in tkinter. The problem that I'm having is that I only want to ask certain questions depending on a condition and skip the question if it isn't met. The code below works to display the text of each cell on the tkinter label, and print on screen whom should have been asked. But linking who should have been asked to the label has proved difficult.

The spread sheet has a value "Male" and "Female" in the first worksheet of the book, and in the second worksheet a list of questions to ask dependent on the gender in the first sheet. each question has its target audience (Male or Female) in the column to the left of it.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import openpyxl

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test of questions")
window.geometry("700x450")
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

def begin_ques():
    begin_btn.place_forget()

    question=tk.StringVar()


    book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
    sheet1 = book.worksheets[0]
    sheet2 = book.worksheets[1]

    gen=sheet1['B2']
    for_gen=sheet2['A2']
    print(for_gen.value)

    question.set(sheet2['B2'].value)
    global Q
    Q=2
    global FG
    FG=2

    def next_ques():

        global FG
        FG+=1
        for_gen=sheet2['A' +str(FG)]
        print(for_gen.value)

        global Q
        Q+=1

        question.set(sheet2['B' + str(Q)].value)

        if sheet2['B' + str(Q)].value == None:
            question.set("Finished")


    next_btn=tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=next_ques)
    next_btn.place(x=575,y=100)
    next_btn.config(height=5, width=5)      


    qus_label = tk.Label(window, textvariable=question, font = LARGE_FONT, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    qus_label.place(x=150, y=100)
    qus_label.config(height=5,width=40)



begin_btn=tk.Button(window, text= "Begin", command=begin_ques)
begin_btn.place(x=320, y=220)
begin_btn.config(height=3, width= 6)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you make your problem more clear ? are you struggling with building conditions ?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. No the condition is simple enough i can read the cell that contains the first value and then compare it to the second. My problem is then going to the next row comparing again and only printing the question if the condition is met else go straight to the next question. If that makes sense?